# How do I separate dictionary values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My dataframe 'json' contains a column with dictionary values. I want to be able to strip the dictionary of the key 'display name', so i just end up with the values of the location.

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: please paste the code in your question, and also place the text from the dictionary, the actual code / text not a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import ast
df['jobLocation'] = df['jobLocation'].dropna().astype('str').apply(ast.literal_eval).str['displayName']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
                   'location': [{'displayName': 'Pitsburgh, PA, USA'}, {'displayName': 'EXAMPLE1, PA, USA'}, {'displayName': 'EXAMPLE2, PA, USA'},
                   {'displayName': 'Pitsburgh, PA, USA'}]})

df1['location']= df1['location'].apply(lambda x: list(x.values())[0].split(", ")[0])
print(df1)
```

output:

```
  user   location
0    a  Pitsburgh
1    b   EXAMPLE1
2    c   EXAMPLE2
3    d  Pitsburgh
```